# PHP - Can't get matched value from foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to make a loop that will detect if you've entered a banned username. But I want to report back to the user what match was made to determine what keyword was used to ban the name. Do you see anything wrong with this?

```
function matchusername($bannedusername, $username)
{
    foreach($bannedusername as $bannedusernam => $value){
        if (strpos($username, $bannedusernam) !== false) {
            $offendingusername = $value;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have some more code that'll check for a valid comment as well and some other various things.

When I add the `=>` `$value` and `$offendingusername = $value;` it seems to just break that loop and skips it and allows the user to post anyway. When I take those 2 parts away, it'll detect a banned username and not allow you to post like it should, but I'd really like it to report the matched value back so in case the users writing a long comment, they can see why they can't post.

I've looked at a lot of other sources and this looks to be the way to do it but it's not working. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: $bannedusername is an array I made of keywords that are banned such as "admin" and profanities. $offendingusername is just an empty variable that I'm trying to assign so it can be called in the error message. It's hard to say what isn't working because this php page is called through ajax and this page is supposed to process the rest. So I don't have a way of really seeing what it is or isn't doing. I've tried getting rid of =>$value and just calling $bannedusernam, and that calls the code but apparently, the variable is null because its just blank when called

Comment: But when I have the code set to what you see above, it literally just skips that function completely, like some kind of syntax is wrong. I ran it through a syntax checker and it should be fine. If I get ride of the $value and $offendingusername = $value, it runs the code and is able to detect a bad username, but that means I can't reference it in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you mixed between key and value in the foreach loop
your variable $bannedusernam is the array key

in order to fix the return, I'de use a boolean variable and use break to ens the foreach, once a match is found

```
function matchusername($bannedusername, $username)
{
 $ret = false;
    foreach($bannedusername as $key => $value){
        if (strpos($username, $value) !== false) {
            $offendingusername = $value;
             $ret = true;
             break;
        }
    }

   if ($ret)
   {
 return $offendingusername;
  } else {
    return $ret;
  } 
}
```

Comment: This successfully runs the code, but when I echo the value out, it's blank.

Comment: as pointed in the other answer, the offendingusername variable is lkcal to the fubxtion. you can either add a global definition of it or return it. I'll fiz my answer to the wnd option

Comment: I created the variable before the function is called, so it should be global already.

Comment: It did not unfortunately, still returns nothing

Comment: can you present some same info, like the bannerusername array, and the calling function?

Comment: Thats literally the entire thing if you don't mind looking at it, there is some profanity in the array but thats for obvious reasons.

Comment: I'm calling that page through ajax and using the javascript on the main page to simply read the contents of the page. So when something is echoed on that php page, thats actually the error message for the main page. If I get this working, I plan on making the bannedcomments function the same thing, so ignore that part for now

Comment: I'll try digging a bit, later on

Comment: Okay, I figured out a solution. Since I was only able to echo it from within the function (for some reason), I just echod the whole error message in the function and left the if statement blank. Now its working fine, and with minimal modification to my existing code. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. Still not sure why it wasn't working with all the other answers but if you're bored later and feel like digging into it, let me know what you find. Either way I'm all good now. Thanks!

Comment: happy to help  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `$offendingusername` as global.

```
function matchusername($bannedusername, $username)
{
    global $offendingusername;

    foreach($bannedusername as $bannedusernam => $value){
        if (strpos($username, $bannedusernam) !== false) {
            $offendingusername = $value;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Another idea is return the match and check it.

```
function matchusername($bannedusername, $username)
{
    foreach($bannedusername as $bannedusernam => $value){
        if (strpos($username, $bannedusernam) !== false) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$ret = matchusername($bannedusername, $username);
if($ret !== false)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Both of these do the same thing my code does and completely skips over the function entirely, allowing the user to post.

Comment: @Syllith please provide the structure or some examples of `$bannedusername`.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Please run `print_r($bannedusername);` and post in your answer so we can see what type of data we are working with.

But until then give this a try:

```
function matchusername($username, $bannedusername){

foreach($bannedusername as $badWord){
    if (strpos($username, $badWord) !== FALSE) {
        return $username;
    }
}
return FALSE;
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```
if($user = matchusername($username, $bannedusername)){

  echo $user . ' You have a banned username.<br>';

}else{

  echo 'Your post was successful.';

}
```